# Access Browser Window from menu item in electron-vue

Tags: javascript, electron-vue

I am trying to add a menu item which will load the url for settings window vue component. I followed this to create my [menu](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-menu/) .

The problem is how can I have a click here access a method inside my createWindow() method in where I can trigger loading of browserWindow for setting file.

I have tried to add a click listener that tries to access function in createWindow() but no luck

mainmenu.js

```
const {Menu} = require('electron')
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app

const template = [
  {
    label: 'Custom',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Setting',
        click (item, focusedWindow) {
          loadSettingWindow()
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

index.js

```
'use strict'

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

let mainWindow
let serviceWindow

const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:9080`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`

function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 563,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1000
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL)

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  function loadSettingWindow () {
    console.log('trigger setting window here')
  }
  require('./mainmenu')
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

I expected that the click event will call trigger the function `loadSettingWindow` but it does not seem to have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't direct access from main to renderer proccess. But you can use [IPC](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to send message to render process and handle it where Vuejs has exists.

Comment: when I try to do add ipcRenderer in mainmenu.js I keep getting undefined when I try to use it on click.